# Gradle not recognizing Groovy files

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am working on a mixed Groovy/Java project using Gradle. Everything compiles fine in eclipse but when I try from the terminal I see.

```
package com.me.model.franklinoh does not exist
import com.me.model.franklinoh.ReportProperty;
```

This has to mean that the groovy classes are not getting compiled and/or linked. I tried adding this to my gradle file just to be sure...

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += ["src/main/java"]
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs += ["src/main/groovy"]
```

But still nothing. Is there anything special that needs done to allow this?

**UPDATE**

This seems to work...

```
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs += ["src/main/java", "src/main/groovy"]
```

But i would still like to compile Java using java and Groovy files using groovy.

Comment: To allow what exactly? Java->Groovy dependencies? Groovy->Java dependencies? Joint compilation? Is `ReportProperty` a Java or Groovy class? Does the compile error occur in a Java or Groovy class? Assuming you applied the `groovy` plugin, your `srcDirs` configuration is redundant. (The one under "update" enables joint compilation, which is what you'll get in Eclipse once you installed the Groovy plugin.)

Comment: ReportProperty is a Groovy class being imported to a Java Class. Error occurs when compiling the java.

Comment: If you only ever want to support Java->Groovy dependencies in this project, reversing the task dependencies between the `JavaCompile` and `GroovyCompile` tasks is good enough. (I answered a SO question on this just a few days ago.) If you additionally want to support Groovy->Java dependencies, you'll need joint compilation.